# unable to send emails from cakephp shell on ubuntu server

Tags: php, email, cakephp, ubuntu

I am unable to receive emails from the cakephp shell on my local server.

I have set up an ubuntu server and have `report.php` located in `myapp/vendors/shells`. `report.php` consists of:

```
<?php 
class EmailShell extends Shell {    

    function main() {
        App::import('Core', 'Controller');
        App::import('Component', 'Email');
        $this->Controller =& new Controller();
        $this->Email =& new EmailComponent(null);
        $this->Email->initialize($this->Controller);

        $this->Email->to = 'me@gmail.com';
        $this->Email->subject = 'spain';
        $this->Email->from = 'blabla <me@gmail.com>';
        $this->Email->send('test email');
        $this->out('email sent');
    }

}
?>
```

I can run this shell in the console and receive the 'email sent' output but no email in my inbox. I can also run a similar action in a controller that successfully sends an email to my email address. In both instances, when the email script is run, it will hang for **1 minute** before successfully/unsuccessfully sending the email.

I appreciate that this has a lot of variables, but since I am able to send an email from a controller, but not the shell, I assume this removes the server as the issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: sending a local mail should be pretty much instantaneous. Are you using some external SMTP server that might be timing out, causing a fallback to local services?

Comment: I don't have an external SMTP server (I don't think) just a local ubunter server with sendmail installed

Answer (score 1):

It could be a DNS issue - if sendmail isn't running as a daemon, it'll start up for every mail send event. If your server's hostname cannot be looked up/resolved by sendmail when it starts, it'll sit and wait for the DNS lookup to time out. Eventually it'll continue on, but this lookup will occur each time sendmail starts.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really strange situation. That it works from the controller at all is spooky. *nix distros like to roll sendmail by default. Php would be able to send email from the controller because PHP runs as a system user, usually with Apache's permissions. Cron, on the other hand, picks up the perms of whoever invoked it (ie, you), except for stuff like (quel shock!) mail servers, etc. And then there's the other twenty million possible things that could prevent cron from using sendmail.

Or hey, how bout those Google SMTP settings: :)

```
$this->Email->smtpOptions = array(  'port'=>'465',
                                    'timeout'=>'30',
                                    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                                    'username'=>'you@gmail.com',
                                    'password'=>'frosting',
                            );
```

Mind you I haven't set up gmail in shells myself before, so no promises, but this came straight out of my controller on my server and it works fine for me.

-- is $this->Email->send() actually sending, or just not erroring out?

```
if($this->Email->send('test email')) {
    $this->out('email sent');
} else {
    $this->out('email falled');
}
```

-- if it says it's sending, what is it trying to send?

```
$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
// Untested, but you get the idea
$mail = $this->Email->send();
$this->out($mail);
```

In addition to Cake's app logs (turn on debugging and logging if needed) in app/tmp/logs/,  /var/log/message, maillog, secure, and Apache's server logs would all reflect this.

-- HTH :)